# get userid from username roblox php

Tags: php, roblox

```php
$user = "linkmon99";              
$page = file_get_contents("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=$user");        
$msg = "> Rolimons : "https://www.rolimons.com/player/$page"
```

The expected output should be:

> https://www.rolimons.com/player/2207291

But it is:

> https://www.rolimons.com/player/%7B%22Id%22:2207291,%22Username%22:%224MHF%22,%22AvatarUri%22:null,%22AvatarFinal%22:false,%22IsOnline%22:false%7D

I hope someone can help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function reads a file into a string. You should be using [`cURL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

```php
$user = "linkmon99";

$ch = curl_init("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=$user");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($data);

echo "> Rolimons : https://rolimons.com/player/$data->Id";

// Output: > Rolimons : https://rolimons.com/player/2207291
```